# How to install pygame automatically when virtual environment is created?

Tags: python, pygame, virtualenv

I am creating a virtual environment `testenv` to run some python project. This is my `environment.yml` file:

```
name: testenv
channels:
- !!python/unicode
  'defaults'
dependencies:
- python=3.5
- pip==9.0.1
- numpy==1.12.0
- jupyter==1.0
- matplotlib==2.0.0
- scikit-learn==0.18.1
- scipy==0.19.0
- pandas==0.19.2
- pip:
  - tensorflow==1.1.0
  - keras==2.0.4
  - plotly==2.7.0
```

I want to add `pygame` to this environenment. However, if I add `pygame==1.9.4` to `dependencies` or `pip`, then the creation of a virtual environment fails:

```
conda env create
```

Therefore I should `source activate testenv` and then install `pygame` manually, but it's not very convenient.

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
pip install pygame
```

Has anybody tried installing `pygame` in the automated way in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create environment:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

To generate your yml:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

More informations in the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#)

Comment: What is `-f`? Could you please explain how should I change the file `environment.yml`?

Comment: Ok, I just installed it manually and exported as you suggested. Nice! Thanks.

Comment: -f is an option to force installation of all package https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html